# Remove alpha compositing knowing the watermark (revert/compensate)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, alpha, watermark

I have watermarked a bunch of images image with PIL (PILLOW in fact).

I have the original watermark and I know exactly how it has been resized and pasted on the image (0.75 opacity). The watermark is essentially black, white and red.

I want to restore images as close as possible as they were originally.

- Is there any chance I could do that automatically?
- What about quality? Is it worth it? Do you have examples of the result of such a process?

If so, how would I manage to do this?

Here is the code I used to watermark the image:

```
logo = Image.open(path)
red, green, blue, alpha = logo.split()
alpha = ImageEnhance.Brightness(alpha).enhance(0.75)
logo.putalpha(alpha)

img = Image.open('...')
img = Image.composite(logo, img, logo)
```

Comment: 1: It's possible. 2: Sure.

Comment: Do you have any example of before/after removing the watermark?

Comment: Which method did you use to watermark the images?

Comment: @miindlek I have used `composite` (cf edit in the question).

Comment: @Torxed Could you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg Not really considering you asked very vague questions and asked us to do the work for you. We'd gladly help you with programming problems but we won't help you find tools or libraries :) The reason why i sad it's possible is because Photoshop obviously made this happen with their "Content aware" feature which is a load of mathematical calculations to do exactly the thing you sad. Assuming that you know the basics you could potentially calculate the offset in color based on knowing the alpha of the overlay. Is it worth it? sure i'd think so, didn't say it would be easy tho.

Comment: @Torxed I understand your opinion but you shouldn't feel the need to comment if it's not constructive and not backed up by experience or evidence.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg I am speaking out of experience, also out of stack-overflow experience where people tend to ask vague questions hoping to get libraries, source or otherwise the code they need from the members instead of trying out stuff themselves (This is clearly covered by the FAQ and is case enough to close a question). I'm sorry if that's harsh and you hating me because i'm the bearer of bad news. You're also spamming down this thread with multiple answers to your own questions instead of updating your progress in the question itself. Stop using gimp and try to use Python, or untag  Python.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg Again, sorry for being blunt. These are (believe it or not) constructive comments, I sincerely suggest you start looking at image-manipulation libraries or algorithms on how to calculate color offset between pixels and/or pattern analysis in pictures. There's much effort to go in to this before a good generic code can emerge, there for the answer is not simple nor do i think you will get it out of the members unless someone is extremely bored and craves points this week :P

Comment: @Torxed I am not talking about complex algorithms, see my answers, which I perfectly satisfactory regarding the question.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg If your answer consists of "which is not really good enough" or "Unfortunately".. Then they are not answers, they're progress reports. Sorry my attention is wanted elsewhere *ejects*..

Answer (score 0):

I've made a mask with of my logo and use GIMP's G'MIC plugin : http://blog.patdavid.net/2014/02/getting-around-in-gimp-gmic-inpainting.html

Here is as far as I can get, which is not really good enough:

[image]

This has been made with inpainting technic, but I am sure I could somehow exploit the fact that my watermark is somewhat transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to unblend the picture, given the watermark and watermarked pictures as input.

Unforunately, the watermarked picture being compressed in jpeg, I couldn't get any better than this :
[image]